# Finding Similar Geometries

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, python

Given a set of coordinates in space:

```
a = [(0,0), (1,0), (10,10), ..., (x,y), (0,0)] # Closed Polygon
b = [(0,0), (1,0), (10,10), ..., (x,y)] # Polyline
c = (x,y) # Point
```

How can one go about and determine how closely related (similar) the shape is to another?

I was thinking I could use some variation on Cosine Similarity, but I am not able to find anything helpful on the internet to point me to a solution performing this type analysis on geometry objects.

Thank you